# Converting JSONArray to List<Object>?

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying deserializes a JSONArray to List. To do it I'm trying use Gson but I can't understand why doesn't works and all values of JSON are null.

How could I do this ?

**JSON**

```
{ "result" : [ 
      { "Noticia" : { 
            "created" : "2015-08-20 19:58:49",
            "descricao" : "tttttt",
            "id" : "19",
            "image" : null,
            "titulo" : "ddddd",
            "usuario" : "FERNANDO PAIVA"
          } },
      { "Noticia" : { 
            "created" : "2015-08-20 19:59:57",
            "descricao" : "hhhhhhhh",
            "id" : "20",
            "image" : "logo.png",
            "titulo" : "TITULO DA NOTICIA",
            "usuario" : "FERNANDO PAIVA"
          } }
    ] }
```

**Deserializes**

```
List<Noticia> lista = new ArrayList<Noticia>();
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("result");

                            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Noticia>>() {}.getType();
                            lista = gson.fromJson(array.toString(), listType);

                            //testing - size = 2 but value Titulo is null
                            Log.i("LISTSIZE->", lista.size() +"");
                            for(Noticia n:lista){
                                Log.i("TITULO", n.getTitulo());
                            }
```

**Class Noticia**

```
public class Noticia implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id;
    private String titulo;
    private String descricao;
    private String usuario;
    private Date created;
    private String image;
```

Comment: The fact that you perform array.toString() looks kinda strange to me.
I would consider to perhaps iterate on the JSONArray and transform each element to Noticia object?

Comment: I don't see getJSONArray method on JsonObject (https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) Please read my answer. Hopefully it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your code :

1. First is that you are using a `getJsonArray()` to get the array,
   which isn't part of **Gson** library, you need to use
   **[getAsJsonArray()](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html#getAsJsonArray-java.lang.String-)** method instead.
2. Second is that you are using `array.toString()` which isn't obvious
   because for the `fromJson` method you need a `jsonArray` as
   parameter and not `String` and that will cause you parse problems, just remove it.

And use the following code to convert your `jsonArray` to `List<Noticia>` :

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Noticia>>() {}.getType();
List<Noticia> lista = gson.fromJson(array, type);
```

And your whole code will be:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JSONArray array = obj.getAsJsonArray("result");

Type type = new TypeToken<List<Noticia>>() {}.getType();
List<Noticia> lista = gson.fromJson(array, type);

//testing - size = 2 but value Titulo is null
Log.i("LISTSIZE->", lista.size() +"");
for(Noticia n:lista){
   Log.i("TITULO", n.getTitulo());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. The variable `obj` is a `JSONObject` and does not have `getAsJsonArray`. When I try `obj.getAsJsonArray("result)"` doesn't works because no have this method. How could I do it ?

Comment: @FernandoPaiva So I think you are using [org.json](json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) so you just use `obj.getJSONArray()` like in your question.

Comment: fronJson takes string as first parameter .

 public <T> T fromJson(String json, Type typeOfT)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem could be something to do with toString() on JSONArray. But are you using  obj.get**As**JsonArray method?

Try this:

```
JSONArray arr = obj.getAsJsonArray("result"); 

            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Noticia>>() {
            }.getType();
            return new Gson().fromJson(arr , listType);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Noticia.java**

```
public class Noticia {
    private String created;
    private String descricao;
    private String id;
    private String image;
    private String titulo;
    private String usuario;
    public String getCreated() {
        return created;
    }
    public void setCreated(String created) {
        this.created = created;
    }
    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }
    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }
    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }
    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }
    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Noticia [created=" + created + ", descricao=" + descricao
                + ", id=" + id + ", image=" + image + ", titulo=" + titulo
                + ", usuario=" + usuario + "]";
    }
}
```

**Result.java**

```
public class Result {
    private Noticia Noticia;

    public Noticia getNoticia() {
        return Noticia;
    }

    public void setNoticia(Noticia noticia) {
        Noticia = noticia;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Result [Noticia=" + Noticia + "]";
    }

}
```

**Item.java**

```
import java.util.List;

public class Item {
    private List<Result> result;

    public List<Result> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Result> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [result=" + result + "]";
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.testgson.beans.Item;

public class Main {
    private static Gson gson;

    static {
        gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String j = "{\"result\":[{\"Noticia\":{\"created\":\"2015-08-20 19:58:49\",\"descricao\":\"tttttt\",\"id\":\"19\",\"image\":null,\"titulo\":\"ddddd\",\"usuario\":\"FERNANDO PAIVA\"}},{\"Noticia\":{\"created\":\"2015-08-20 19:59:57\",\"descricao\":\"hhhhhhhh\",\"id\":\"20\",\"image\":\"logo.png\",\"titulo\":\"TITULO DA NOTICIA\",\"usuario\":\"FERNANDO PAIVA\"}}]}";
        Item r = gson.fromJson(j, Item.class);
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

**Final result**

```
Item [result=[Result [Noticia=Noticia [created=2015-08-20 19:58:49, descricao=tttttt, id=19, image=null, titulo=ddddd, usuario=FERNANDO PAIVA]], Result [Noticia=Noticia [created=2015-08-20 19:59:57, descricao=hhhhhhhh, id=20, image=logo.png, titulo=TITULO DA NOTICIA, usuario=FERNANDO PAIVA]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You parse json, that looks like

```
{ "result" : [ 
  { 
        "created" : "2015-08-20 19:58:49",
        "descricao" : "tttttt",
        "id" : "19",
        "image" : null,
        "titulo" : "ddddd",
        "usuario" : "FERNANDO PAIVA"
   },
  { 
        "created" : "2015-08-20 19:59:57",
        "descricao" : "hhhhhhhh",
        "id" : "20",
        "image" : "logo.png",
        "titulo" : "TITULO DA NOTICIA",
        "usuario" : "FERNANDO PAIVA"
      }
] }
```

You need to make another object Item and parse a list of them.

```
public class Item{
    Noticia noticia; 
}
```

Or you can interate through JSONArray, get field "noticia" from each then parse Noticia object from given JSONObject.

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin Ex :**
we getting response in form of JSONArry

```
call.enqueue(object : Callback<JsonArray> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<JsonArray>, response: Response<JsonArray>) {

            val list = response.body().toString()
            val gson = Gson()
            val obj: CitiesList? = gson.fromJson(list, CitiesList::class.java)
            cityLiveData.value = obj!!
           

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<JsonArray>, t: Throwable) {
          
        }

    })
```

Here CitiesList CitiesList::class.java is the ArrayList of Cities object

```
class CitiesList : ArrayList<CitiesListItem>()
```

Before using **GSON** add dependancey in Gradle

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'

}
```